# Model-View-Presenter vs Model-View-ViewModel for embedded application in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, design-patterns, mvvm, mvp

We are starting a larger embedded application in C++ and using LVGL UI library written in C.
I would like to know which architecture to choose, the MVP, MVVM, or maybe something simplified.
Can MVVM be done correctly without native support for data bidding?
What would you choose?

Comment: For the tag [C++] this is definitely "Opinion Based".

Comment: I would say write a kiddy app (something like a to-do list) in all three and see which is easiest to write with LVGL on your platform.